# Some resources on quantising spin 2 fields in flat and curved space time

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I want to understand how one can quantize spin 2 fields. Any resource which starts with a flat background before moving on to curved backgrounds would be great. So far, I have found this [article](https://doi.org/10.1088/0370-1298/65/3/301) but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Just a question aside, are spin 2 tensor fields always connected to spacetime curvature? Do you know?

Comment: I'm not sure, and that's why I worded my question in this way. I'm looking for quantisation of arbitrary spin 2 fields in some other fixed background.

Comment: The first QFT you study on a curved background should not be one involving fields of spin 2.

Comment: It isn't. But I need to learn this for a research project. I've previously looked at scalar fields in AdS, and I've gone through Birrel and Davies as well.